# How do i properly use scripts in nodejs app with ejs as a preprocessor?

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have the following script and html body => https://codepen.io/malditojapones/pen/YzqNzWq.

It's supposed to modify an existing div and add questions and answers from an array declared within the script.

In codepen it works just fine. But on mi nodejs app (using express for backend, and ejs as a html preprocesor, i don´t know if this makes a difference or not) the script doesn´t load on the page and doesn´t add any content.

The js file is inside the public folder where mi css and images folders are also located and those work fine. The script is included in my index.html with script tags and the same path-syntax as my css files and images files (all inside public folder which is used by the app in index.js using this line:

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

I know there´s probably several mistakes here, i´m just starting to build projects and i couldn´t find an answer to this online. Thanks in advance for any help.